How to access physical Ethernet port on Windows 11 via WSL2 to send raw packets (EtherCAT)
I want to send raw Ethernet packets from an application (EtherCAT Master, SOEM) inside a WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) to a Physical Ethernet port on my PC to an external EtherCAT slave which is attached to it. I tried a lot of different things and nothing did remotely work. For all tests I have a EtherCAT slave attached to the port in question. The slave works with a dedicated PC with an Ubuntu running.
Do you maybe know how to achieve that? Routing does not work as i do not use TCP/IP packets but EtherCAT packets. The most promising way in my opinion would be to just bridge the port of the WSL with the physical one, so that all traffic whatsoever on the WSL port will be sent out to the physical one.
Thank you very much in advance
I tried:

set the WSL networking mode in .wslconfig to mirrored. This shows the Ethernet port, and I can access it via the EtherCAT master, but no packets are sent over it (I checked with Wireshark, and it is dead silent) and the slave is not accessible. Should this work also with raw packets? Does anybody tried that?
I tried to bridge the HyperV Ethernet port from WSL (which is created by Windows) with the physical port. This was not possible as the HyperV port did not show up, either in the GUI or in the power shell (when using Netsh bridge). Thee WSL port is hidden, and when I got the ID or GUID of it in power shell, the Netsh bridge "Did not know the adapter".
I tried to bind the WSL bridge not to internal but to the physical port in the Hyper-V Manager which was not possible due to an "Access Denied" error, but I think this will anyways not work as I set the adapter settings on the host machine and not the WSL itself.

